# Manage Cache collection by multiple properties

Tags: c#, .net, caching

I have `Sensor` class which contains few properties: `id, a, b`. 
Another class called `SensorCache` and responsible for manage in memory cache for my sensor collection. 
`SensorCache` implements "Cache aside pattern" see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589799.aspx)

`SensorCache` works in traditional way - each Sensor request (the requests made by the `id` property) first goes to `SensorCache`:

- if it already exists in memory - `SensorCache` return it
- if not in memory, it brings the required Sensor from my DB, save into memory cache object (represented by `Dictionary') and return it.

Currently my dictionary key is based on the `Sensor.id` field. 
I got a new requirement to return a `Sensor` by 2 fields (`a` and `b`) and keep my cache logic.

My cache object currently built to search by single property (`Sensor.id`) so I need to think about new structure which able to search in memory by 2 different options: `Sensor.id` or 'Sensor.a' and 'Sensor.b' pairs.

What is the best approach to handle this?

I thought about holding two different objects, one for each kind of search but this approach will consume much more memory (x2) so I want to hear another ideas before doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a separate class that implements `IEquatable` and overrides `GetHashCode` (and sometimes you have to, to achieve the required performance) but in this simple case, it sounds like you could use [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.tuple), that is, `Dictionary<Tuple<(type of a), (type of b)>, Sensor>`.

Comment: I thought about Tuple but if I understood right, it means to keep to cache objects in memory: one for search by id field and one for  search by (a,b) fields...

Comment: Yes. I don't see how you could have any solution that avoids this and still keeps constant-time lookups. Keep in mind that the memory consumption is limited to the storage of "`id`", and "`Tuple<a, b>`" plus some overhead for the dictionary buckets. The `Sensor` instances are only stored once and the dictionaries keep only references to them (assuming that `Sensor` is a class and not a `struct`). In general, you don't want to optimize for memory use as opposed to speed unless you can show a need.